# Set Django login to expire differently for different users

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-sessions

I've found SESSION_COOKIE_AGE and similar settings, but they're global. Is it possible to tell django's auth module to expire logins differently based on different user types? So, for example, have superusers expire in a week, but regular users expire in 6 hours (or at browser close)?

The only thing I've found that seems like it might work is to set the expiry on the session:

request.session.set_expiry(value)

But it doesn't seem to work to expire the user, just to get rid of the session data.